# replace characters in string until different character

Tags: php, str-replace

OK lets assume I have

```
   $value = '0.0005304';
```

I'm struggling to work out how I can remove all instances of 0 
until another character is detected.
So in the case above the end result would be 5304

I know I should show code working out however I'm unsure on how to do this so don't know where to start looking.

Any help would be appreciated

** Added **
The 2 numbers are stock market prices , open & close
basically I want to deduct the open from the close

this value will be the difference between the 2
example open = 1.23456 close = 1.23446 is a difference of -0.00010 
I would want this represented as -10 points

Hope this explains more

Comment: All instances of 0 until another character would be `.0005304`

Comment: i'm not sure its what yuo want - https://regex101.com/r/ak4d72/1

Comment: This question and its answers are slight modifications of this near duplicate page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782414/trim-any-zeros-at-the-beginning-of-a-string-using-php and this other duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34204005/removing-leading-zeros-from-number-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Decimal calculations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246595/php-decimal-calculations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$value = '0.0005304';

$value = (int)str_replace('.','', $value);

var_dump($value); //output 5304
```

`str_replace` will remove the `.` and `(int)` will cast it to int which will remove all the `0`s

Answer (score 2):

[Trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) off the zeroes, or in your case, the zeroes and the decimal.

```
$value = ltrim($value, '0.');
```

I don't know if referring to this as "replace characters" is accurate, though. It seems we're replacing them with nothing.

Comment: I hate that this works lol. https://3v4l.org/11V8A Can you explain why the other 0's get trimmed even tho you're only telling it to trim 0.?

Comment: This is a much better solution. Even though OP did not specify, this will work for `3.00052` or the like, whereas the other answer won't.

Comment: @WillParky93 The second argument is a character mask. It will trim any included characters. For `'0.'` It trims `0` and `.`.

Comment: I'll elaborate a bit more in what this is intended for in the origianl post,
give me a minute :)